# Has a second season of Mysterious Girlfriend X been announced?

Tags: mysterious-girlfriend-x

After seeing this anime I was kind of confused if it is over or if there is more to come. Has a second season of this series been announced? I am asking this because I am interested in knowing that how this series will end. So do I have to wait for the next season or do I have to start searching for this manga and start reading it. (Actually I have never tried reading manga ever so I always see Anime)

Comment: I edited your question to make it on-topic on Anime.SE. If you have some confusion about the show, I recommend asking a question about what you're confused about. That's what this site is all about, providing explanations for plot details that may have left you puzzled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no news at current time that hints to a second season. [Anime news network link here](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=13899). The manga was completed years ago so i doubt that the anime is getting any continuation.