# Have there been any announcements or news as to why the second season of Mysterious Girlfriend X was never made?

Tags: mysterious-girlfriend-x

I love *Mysterious Girlfriend X* anime so much, and I feel it left on a cliff-hanger. I would love to see a second season.

Have there been any announcements or news as to why a second season was never made?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Has a second season of Mysterious Girlfriend X been announced?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/29708/has-a-second-season-of-mysterious-girlfriend-x-been-announced)

Comment: @Programming Champion The question is asking for the reason why a second season never came out. It is not asking if a season has been announced. Take note of the difference :)

Comment: I think this could be on topic, esp if it's rephrased towards something like "has there been any announcement regarding why only one season was made" or "has there been any announcement about why it was ended on a cliffhanger". As it stands now, it could arguably be asking for an opinion or about a future event (bc no second season yet doesn't mean no second season ever), so it's questionable at the moment.

Comment: @kuwaly Ah, I see what you mean. I'll try and edit it.

Comment: This whole thing sounds rather...... *mysterious*, don't you think? Haha, I'll see myself out....

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find news regarding this so I think there will never be likely a second season (but I'm constantly hoping it will still happen, too). Possible reasons include:

1. **Money**. It is expensive to make anime and if the manga and anime did not sell well, it is highly unlikely they'll get another season. Relevant links: [Why don't anime shows finish the manga?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/34468/why-dont-anime-shows-finish-the-manga) [How much does a typical anime episode or series cost to make?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4175/how-much-does-a-typical-anime-episode-or-series-cost-to-make/4179#4179)
2. **Not enough content to cover**. But seeing as the manga is finished, it's more likely that reason 1 is the case.

I've finished the manga so if you really want to continue the story, read it because as far as I know, the anime skipped some parts. I'll update this if I find relevant news.